# The existence of solution of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: algorithms

Given a multivariate polynomial of degree 4 on $v$ (real) variables such that there are $N$ terms in the polynomial. Is there an efficient algorithm to verify if it has a solution?

Not aware of any algorithm for this problem. Can someone please comment.

I think the solution itself can be calculated by Newton Raphson algorithm (but I am unaware of its running time complexity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The problem is NP-hard.

It is NP-hard to test whether a system of quadratic equations has any solution.  See [Reduction from vertex-cover to system of quadratic equations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150339/755), [Determine whether the system of equations is underdetermined or overdetermined](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/146258/755) (related: [3-SAT and Systems of Nonlinear Modular Equations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77985/755)).

Let $f_1(x)=0$, ..., $f_k(x)=0$ be a system of quadratic equations, where each $f_i$ is a multivariate quadratic polynomial on the variables.  Define

$$g(x) = f_1(x)^2 + \dots + f_k(x)^2.$$

Then the single equation $g(x)=0$ has a solution if and only if the system of quadratic equations $f_1(x)=0$, ..., $f_k(x)=0$ has a solution.  Moreover, $g$ has degree 4.

This reduction proves that your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: thank you. Not much background in mathematics so a follow up: Does that mean the worst case run time of Newton Raphson or bisection method is exponential w.r.t the size of problem?

Comment: @xyz, I believe the bisection method can only be used for univariate polynomials.  I'm not familiar with the complexity-theory worst-case running time of Newton Raphson.  If the above argument is right, presumably it must imply that its worst-case running time can be exponential in some settings, but I am not able to independent verify that or explain why it might be true.

Comment: Just as a comment, it might be more efficient in practice to compute the cylindrical algebraic decomposition of the polynomial, despite that algorithm being $O(2^{2^v})$ in the worst case.

Answer (score -1):

Mainly there are two methods, estimation of Eigenvalues of a matrix is the command method we use.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Eigen/Core>
    #include <Eigen/Geometry>
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <unsupported/Eigen/Polynomials>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <vector>
    #include <complex>

    template<typename T> 
    class RootFinder {
        public:
            RootFinder() = default;
            ~RootFinder() = default;

            inline std::vector<std::complex<T>> calculateEigenValuesOfMatrix(Eigen::MatrixXd A){
                Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> ES(A);
                std::vector<std::complex<T>> eigen_values;
                for(int i =0;i<ES.eigenvalues().rows();++i){
                    eigen_values.push_back(ES.eigenvalues()[i]);
                }
                return eigen_values;
            };

            inline std::vector<std::complex<T>> calculateRootsOfPoly(Eigen::VectorXd coeffs){
                Eigen::PolynomialSolver<T, Eigen::Dynamic> solver;
                solver.compute(coeffs);
                const typename Eigen::PolynomialSolver<T, Eigen::Dynamic>::RootsType & r = solver.roots();
                std::vector<std::complex<T>> roots;
                for(int i =0;i<r.rows();++i)
                {
                    roots.push_back(r[i]);
                }
                return roots;
            };

        private:
            
    };
```

Here some of example how to use this method to find root of any higher order polynomial https://github.com/GPrathap/motion_planning/blob/main/motion_planning_alg/src/main.cpp

[image]

For more information check these slides: https://github.com/GPrathap/motion_planning/blob/main/lectures/mpav_pontryagin_s_optimal_control_theory.pdf (page 20)

Comment: How does this answer *Is there an efficient algorithm to **verify if it has a solution**?*